# Extract files which have more than 5 lines, and keep same filename

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have multipe files containing errors in annual reports. Each file name have .mvt extension. It is not necessary that every file has error. I have found that when errors appear OR not there is always header in the file, which is 5 lines.
It is not necessary to see every file (more than 300 files).

I wonder if `awk` can be helpful like `awk 'NR> 5' filename.mvt`, but problem is that I have to test each file with `if` `else`. I want to copy (with `cp` command) files, so name remain the same, files that contain more than 5 line.

Comment: It strikes me as more useful to look in the files for the actual error (if it can be detected), than to scan the files for the consequence of the error.  What is the error, and how have you determined that some files contain it and some don't, or is the only error that some files are "longer than others"?

Comment: I mentioned that system creating files for each movment. Every file is starting with header and header are almosst common and contains 5 line. So i realized that if file has more than 5 lines that indicate it contains error.

Answer (score 1):

The following command will detect all regular file in or below the current directory that has names ending in `.mvt` and that are longer than five lines.  For each of those files, it will output the file's pathname.

```
find . -type f -name '*.mvt' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        if [ "$( wc -l <"$pathname" )" -gt 5 ]; then
            printf "%s\n" "$pathname"
        fi
    done' sh {} +
```

To copy each of those files to some directory (it is unclear what you *actually* want to do with these files), you may want to do the following:

```
mkdir -p possible-error-files || exit 1

find . -type f -name '*.mvt' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        if [ "$( wc -l <"$pathname" )" -gt 5 ]; then
            printf "%s\n" "$pathname"
            cp "$pathname" possible-error-files
        fi
    done' sh {} +
```

In both commands, I pass the contents of the file to `wc -l` count the number of lines.

As an alternative, you may use `awk` to do both the counting of lines and the output of the pathname (modifying the second command from above):

```
mkdir -p possible-error-files || exit 1

find . -type f -name '*.mvt' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        if awk "BEGIN { err=1 } FNR > 5 { print FILENAME; err=0; exit } END { exit err }" <"$pathname"
        then
            cp "$pathname" possible-error-files
        fi
    done' sh {} +
```

Or, with GNU `awk`:

```
mkdir -p possible-error-files || exit 1

find . -type f -name '*.mvt' -exec awk '
    FNR > 5 {
        print FILENAME
        system("cp \"" FILENAME "\" possible-error-files")
        nextfile
    }' {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution:

```
for mvt_file in *.mvt; do
    if [ "$(awk 'END {if(NR > 5) print "yes"}' "$mvt_file")" == "yes" ]; then
        cp "$mvt_file" "$mvt_file - copy"
    fi
done
```

You can also do:

```
for mvt_file in *.mvt; do
    if [ "$(wc -l < "$mvt_file")" -gt 5 ]; then
        cp "$mvt_file" "$mvt_file - copy"
    fi
done
```

Either should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

We can use below script to find the file which having more than 5 lines

```
for i in filename1 filename2 filename3 file; do j=`awk '{print NR}' $i| sort -nr| sed -n '1p'`; if [[ $j  > 5 ]]; then echo $i; fi; done| sed '1i below are filenames which having lines more than 5'
```

Comment: Note that the `awk` command could simply be `awk 'FNR>5 { print FILENAME; exit }'`.

Comment: Thanks for feed back yes i agree with your comment